# Correct Way to Shutdown an Addin While Outllook Still Runs

Tags: c#, vsto, outlook-addin

I have an outlook addin I'm writing in VSTO.  I want to exit the addin in a certain case.  System.Application.Windows.Forms.Exit() exits outlook completely.  I just want the addin to shutdown.  I can't call ThisAddIn_Shutdown() because it is private.  What is the correct practice to shut the addin down? This addin doesn't continuously run, it only calls a routine when a button is pressed.  I want to stop execution if the current item is not a mail item, but I'm not sure what method to call or the correct way to handle it.  I don't see any examples on MSDN either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I just want the addin to shutdown.... it only calls a routine when a button is pressed.

Simply disable the button (grey it out) and stop any running background processes. Any addin which *disappears* would become circumspect that it is *failing out* to the user which is not the impression one should give.

Comment: how can you disable/grey out the button?

Comment: @shenk set its `Enabled` property to false.